# Time format coming as number in JSON while rendering data from Excel

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on a use-case where i am uploading the data from excel, parsing it to JSON and using the data for subsequent API call in ReactJS.
I am able to upload excel and parse the data. However, parsing the excel data to JSON, the time format is getting changed to number format.
How can i change the time to orignal format in ReactJS?

JSON value [
  {

```
"startTime": 0.16666666666666666,
"returnStartTime": 0.20833333333333334
```

},
  {

```
"startTime": 0.20833333333333334,
"returnStartTime": 0.20833333333333334
```

}
]

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: `parsing the excel data to JSON` what framework are you using for that?

Comment: I am doing it using ReactJS

Comment: Whatever excel code you have is sending the numeric value of those times (in fraction of a day) rather than the display value.  Probably easier to change that code to send the strings instead, rather than build a javascript function to convert the decimals.